# Access query with unionall or crosstab in asp not working

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ms-access-2007

Here is a sample access query which I have(query ref/name  - abovequery)

```
select column_date, sum(field1), sum(field2) from table
group by column_date
union all
select 'Total' as column_date, sum(field1), sum(field2) from table
```

When I try to access the SQL query in browser using below code in asp, it displays only heading.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from abovequery"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note when I copy the output of above query into a table and use the same asp code, it works fine. So obviously it is an issue of executing "UNION" query in asp. I wonder if there is any solution for this. The same problem happens when I try to execute crosstab query also.

New: This is what I tried now

- but its last row with total is not correctly aligned along with the other main data rows.

Here is a sample access query which I have created now

1st query - query1

```
select column_date, sum(field1), sum(field2) from table
group by column_date
```

2nd query - query2

```
select 'Total' as column_date, sum(field1), sum(field2) from table
```

asp code

```
<html>
<body>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from query1"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from query2"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">

<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my third try to fix alignment problem

```
<html>
<body>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from query1"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>

<%
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from query2"
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
<td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you running two queries as a union? Run them as two queries.

Comment: The second query is to display its total. I want to display it's total in the same page at the bottom of the data.

Comment: Why not run the first query, create an array with GetRows and do the same for the second query?

Comment: I don't know about GetRows or Array. I will look into it. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: You might like to read http://www.aspfaqs.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=161. GetRows also allows you to close the connection quickly, a good idea with ASP Classic and MS Access.

Comment: @Hansup. I just tried again as per your advise (as I updated  in my original question) but it doesn't work. It displays only one row from first query and the one and only row from second total query. Can you please assist where I'm mistake?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was talking about "This is my third.....". It doesn't work. Even I tried the way you advised but it didn't work also.

Comment: finally it worked...I created new adodb.recordset for second query but kept same adodb.connection for both...it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description sounds like the recordset contains no records.  Confirm this point.

```
<html>
<body>
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT * from abovequery"
rs.Open sql, conn, 3 ' adOpenStatic '
Response.Write("RecordCount: " & rs.RecordCount)
rs.close
conn.close
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, do you mean I should add (3 'adOpenStatic') Response.Write ("RecordCount:" & rs.RecordCount) in my code?

Comment: I intended a temporary substitution of your existing ASP code, simply to verify whether or not the recordset is empty.

Comment: @user1449596 Another good read for not trying to run the two queries as one. Get the data, if there is any, get the totals. Or vice versa.

Comment: @user1449596 You can try to figure out why the query is not returning any rows and fix it.  I might do that simply out of curiosity.  However, I think you would be better off to follow @Remou 's advice: open a recordset for only the detail rows (the first half of your UNION query).  `Response.Write` those rows, then open a recordset for the sums and `Response.Write` that row.  And if the first recordset *still* contains no rows, at least you will have a simpler problem to trouble shoot.

Comment: @Hansup...I really don't understand what you want me to try..I tried as below but it doesn't display total exactly at the bottom of the main data.

Comment: @Hansup. Please note I updated my main question with the latest code I tried. Thank you.